# use command line/console tool like artisan in Laravel for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, laravel, spring-boot, laravel-artisan

I'm a newbie in java spring boot.

I need to create a web app like laravel with spring boot

I want to know: are there any best practices like laravel boilerplate for web applications? with command-line tools like artisan to create classes that we need?

in another word, do you know someone or a repository(s) in GitHub that gathers classes and tools and libraries for common web applications with spring boot with console cmd tools to develop spring boot? like laravel

I know we have spring starter online tools like [this](https://start.spring.io/) for creating the first template of our custom project. or many starters templates like [this](https://github.com/naveensingh43/traning-/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters). but I need console command-line tools like artisan to add models controllers or anything that developers need with CLI. like artisan

Comment: Did you get anything?

Comment: Check out Jhipster https://www.jhipster.tech/. It's a similar one